# How to find the average time between consecutive events?

Tags: statistics, average, means

The question is,

On average 3 times a day during 8.00 a.m. to 8.00 p.m. electricity power breakdowns are occurred in a certain city. What is the average time between two consecutive power breakdowns?

I am trying to find the answer for this question. I have 2 approaches.
The first one is since there are 3 power cuts, the average time between two consecutive power breakdowns should be 4 hours.

The second approach is since there are 3 power breakdowns, only 2 pair of consecutive power breakdowns can be considered and therefore the answer is 6 hours.

Which approach is the correct answer? Or are both wrong?
Can anyone clarify this?

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: A confusing question indeed ...

Answer (score 1):

If there are 3 power breakdowns and you want to find the average time between 2 of them you need to first find out the middle time between 8am and 8 pm which is 12pm. Then you must figure out the first power outage time and the last power outage time. this is tough to answer but if i had to sat the intervoles are 8 hours apart.